# Selenium While Loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium-ide

```
 </head>
    <body>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">test</td></tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//div[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//div[@id='dataTableContent']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=backButton</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//div[@id='dataTableContent']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=backButton</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//div[@id='dataTableContent']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=backButton</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//div[@id='dataTableContent']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=backButton</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
        <td>//div[contains(@class,'ui-widget-overlay')]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to click through 4 sections.
All have the same path, but not the same tablediv.

/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td
--> 1 to 4

How can I do this, thats the code are minimalize,
how can I use a while loop here?

The Code in Selenium has 18 commands..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Selenium IDE rather than WebDriver, the only "while" loop that you'll be able to execute is by executing plain old javascript.

```
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>iterator</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
  <td>while (iterator <= 4) { browserBot.click("/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[" + iterator + "]" }</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

You'll of course need to play with it, this is pseudo-code but will give a pretty decent idea of how to solve it using the IDE.